# how to install Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core on portable library

Tags: nuget, portable-class-library, azure-cosmosdb

I get error installing documentDB nuget package.

Could not install package 'Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 1.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Any ideas?  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Core package actually targets [NetStandard 1.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library), not .Net Core specifically.

NetStandard is a library that acts as API for different runtimes and it's much more powerfull than PCL because it's platform-agnostic:

[image: NetStandard compatibility chart]

This means that the DocumentDb.Core package can run on .Net Core 1.0, .Net Framework, Xamarin and UWP.

If you are creating a PCL, I would recommend you to [create a NetStandard library instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library#comparison-to-portable-class-libraries).

It will let your library support a much wider universe of platforms and the great thing is that, if a new platform comes along that supports NetStandard 1.6 (for example), your library will work without needing to recompile or republish it.

Comment: thanks for that info.  This means I need to change my existing PCL library which is pretty good size. that sucks...

Comment: Try this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2015) to migrate a PCL to NetStandard.

Comment: do you use PCL or Shared library?  Which do you suggest?

Comment: A NetStandard library will always be the best option over a PCL. It's probably the one with the brightest future :)

Answer (score 1):

This error message tells us that this assembly `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core` is not supported on portable library. From [this assembly nuget site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core/), we know that This client library enables client applications **targeting .NET Core** to connect to the Azure DocumentDB service. If you want to use Azure DocumentDB library, please try to see if this assembly works `Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB`

Comment: This is not the same nuget or it doesn't work.  It adds Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client but it can't find this object/dll

Comment: What do you want to do use this assembly? Which project will reference your class library (portable)? .NET core or UWP application or any others?

Comment: I was testing azure documentDB generated project 'starter app' and it was using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.Core.  Starter app is using shared project .

Comment: Why does DocumentDB charges for space when I don't even have any data on Azure?  I got charged about $36 and it's not even end of the month.